# How can I count values using If and Countif from a specific range?

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

I would like to know if its possible to count a number of value by doing a conditional statement example below:

If Cell A has value of cell range equal to "yes" then Cell B will display the count of Cell A that has the value of "yes".

```
Name1 - Yes     Count-Name1: 2
Name2 - No      Count-Name2: 0
Name3 - Yes     Count-Name3: 1
Name1 - Yes
```

Comment: Please post your attempt and difficulties you are facing with it. Hint: `COUNTIFS` function can be used to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. See my example screenshot below and reference [How To Count If Cell Contains Text Or Part Of Text In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2874-excel-count-if-cell-contains-text.html)

. Please let me know if this fixes your ask, or if there is something else. Thanks,
Carter

[image: Excel CountIFS with partial match]